# triangle free graph $ \sum_{v \in V(G)} deg ^{2} v \leq mn $

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am studying for an exam in a graph theory class. Here is the exercise I need some help with.

> Let $G$ a triangle free graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges.
>
> (a) Prove that there exists vertices $x,y$ in $G$ such that $
>  \displaystyle{ \text{deg(x)} + \text{ deg(y)} \leq n}$.
>
> (b) Prove that: $\displaystyle{ \sum_{v \in V(G)} \text{ deg } ^{2} v
>  \leq mn }$

I have done (a) but I have some trouble with (b).

Comment: I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218292/proof-about-graph-with-no-triangle?rq=1 so the moderators can close the question.